# Library with no TLS symbols gives error : dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dlopen

The following call fails to dynamically load the library, complaining that it cannot load more objects with static TLS:

```
dlopen("libfoo.so",RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW);
```

However after I examine it:

```
readelf -a libfoo.so | grep TLS
```

There are no TLS symbols.

Any ideas why it would be failing to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas why it would be failing to load

This library probably depends on some other library with a TLS segment.

You can run `ldd libfoo.so`, and then `readelf -l` on each dependent library. One of them has to have a `TLS` segment, or you wouldn't be getting the error you are getting.